# Even after I press "Publish release", GitHub release stays as Draft

Tags: github

[Creating a GitHub release](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/) usually works well, but for [one particular project](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Quadtree) I can't seem to be able to publish: the Draft stays a Draft and never gets published.

It happens both for forks and for projects I created from scratch.
Happens with both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same issue, in my case the solution was the "Tag version" field at the top of the form.  As long as I left that field blank, clicking "Publish Release" did nothing and the release stayed in draft.  As soon as I added the version number to it, a tag was added and the release was published.